# Trying To Count line numbers on .txt file with using ''EOF'' But Loop Goes Infinite. 'in C'

Tags: c, io, txtextcontrol

```
int main(void) {
    Fr = fopen("ContactList.txt", "r");
    while (fscanf(Fr, "%d", &num) != EOF) {
        ++counter;
    }
```

`ContactList.txt` is similar like this:

```
Name Surname XXX-XXX-XXXX XXX-XXX-XXXX Adress Adress Mail
Name(1) Surname XXX-XXX-XXXX XXX-XXX-XXXX Adress Adress Mail
Name(2) Surname XXX-XXX-XXXX XXX-XXX-XXXX Adress Adress Mail
...
```

Comment: show `ContactList.txt`

Comment: ContactList.txt is too long to post but goes similar like this =

Name Surname XXX-XXX-XXXX XXX-XXX-XXXX Adress Adress Mail
Name(1) Surname XXX-XXX-XXXX XXX-XXX-XXXX Adress Adress Mail
Name(2) Surname XXX-XXX-XXXX XXX-XXX-XXXX Adress Adress Mail

All lines contains different info

Comment: If other than content that can be parsed `%d` is not appropriate as a numerical value.

Comment: `while (fscanf(Fr, "%d", &num) != EOF){` --> `while (fscanf(Fr, "%d", &num) == 1){`  Then the next input will be EOF or some non-numeric text.

Comment: `"%d"` is for parsing text into an `int`, not for parsing `"Name Surname  ..."`

Comment: use `fgets` instead of.

Comment: Thanks Guys for all those help

Comment: fgets never returns EOF. Never use any library function without first reading its documentation.

Answer (score 2):

`fscanf` will return 0 for `"%d"` format when the next character from the input stream cannot start a number.  You just test for `EOF`, which is only returned at end of file.  You keep trying to parse a number and `fscanf` stubbornly tells you there is no number... endless loop indeed.

The file does not even contain numbers.  Why do you attempt to parse a number?

Answer (score 1):

The `fscanf()` function will scan text according to the format string you provide, *leaving unconsumed anything it cannot match to the format*.  With the format you present, it will consume any leading whitespace and then try to match whatever follows to a possibly-signed decimal integer.  It will return `1` if it successfully matches an (one) integer, and `0` if it encounters non-whitespace that it cannot match as an integer.  It will return `EOF` only in the event that it reaches `EOF` while consuming the leading whitespace.

Therefore, if your file contains anything other than whitespace and decimal numbers, the scan will eventually reach a point where it cannot parse a number from the input (and therefore returns `0` without consuming anything), but you keep asking it to try again.

What you could do instead depends on the format of the file, and on what you mean by "count line numbers".  Based on your wording and your `scanf()` format, I first thought your data had literal line numbers in it (like, for instance, BASIC or Fortran source code might have), and you wanted to count those.  I now suspect that what you meant is that you simply want to count the number of lines.  If *that's* what you are after then you might do something like this:

```
char c;
size_t count = 1;

while (fscanf(Fr, "%*[^\n]%c", &c) == 1) {
    count += 1;
}
```

That `scanf()` format scans and ignores everything up to a newline or EOF, then consumes the next character if there is one (which can only be a newline).  It returns `1` if and only if it successfully scans a newline.  Initializing `count` to `1` corresponds to viewing the newlines as line *separators*, as opposed to line *terminators*, so that there is one more line than there are newlines.

There are other approaches, too, and it may be that the one above doesn't suit you perfectly, but it should give you an idea of how you can proceed.

Comment: Your suggested code fails on empty lines (`%[` registers a *matching failure* in that case and then won't go on to process the `%c`)

Answer (score 0):

fscanf() returns the number of values scanned and formatted. You are comparing that to EOF, which is probably -1. Therefore your loop will run forever even if you don't read anything.

Change to fgets() rather than fscanf() - simpler and faster and will read spaces. fgets will read up to the next newline, which is very useful when processing text files.

```
char buffer[80];  // 80 might not be enough. Your call.
 while (fgets(buffer, 80, fr)) != NULL){
...
}
```

Comment: Add `++counter;` to the loop and you meet OP's title goal: "Trying To Count line numbers on .txt file"

Answer (score 0):

To count the number of lines in a file:

```
int main(void) {
  Fr = fopen("ContactList.txt", "r");
  if (Fr) {
    unsigned long long count = 0;
    int previous = '\n';
    while ((ch = fgetc(Fr)) != EOF) {
      if (previous == '\n') count++;
      previous = ch;
    }
    printf("Line Count %llu\n", count); 
    fclose(Fr);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

This counts the last line in a file even if it does not end with `'\n'`.